# Dovecot, getting error: Mail access for users with UID 222 not permitted

Tags: email, dovecot

When I attempt to login to my Dovecot IMAP server I get this error:

```
 dovecot: imap(ec2-user): Error: user *theuser*: Couldn't drop privileges: Mail access for users with UID 222 not permitted
```

What is going on? HELP!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dovecot restricts the users that can login via the `first_valid_uid` setting -- the assumption is that system users (which should not be logging in to an IMAP server) all have UIDs below a certain threshold, and regular users (who should be the ones logging in to an IMAP server) have UIDs above a certain threshold.

So, first make sure you're not logging in as a system user (like `postmaster`).  If you are logging in as a regular user, check your Dovecot config and make sure that the `first_valid_uid` setting accurately reflects your policies (or that of your distribution) for the UID range that represents regular users.